# Can TWO different points on the number line ever be represented by the SAME infinite decimal?

Tags: math-history, decimal-expansion

So I am visualizing this problem, and on the surface it seems like there is no way two individual and unique values could have the same infinite decimal representation.  Any thoughts on this?  It is for my History of Mathematics course. Thanks, peeps.

Comment: No way.  The numerical representation of a point on the line is its decimal expansion.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought.  The question is wanting me to get into the why or why not... but having it reinforced makes me feel less crazy! Thanks man, appreciate it.

Comment: No, they cannot. But conversely, two different decimal expansions *can* represent the exact same number, such as $0.999\dots = 1.000\dots$. Numbers can inject into their decimal expansions but not the other way around.

Comment: The main reason why the answer to this is no is that the set of real numbers can be thought of as the set of Cauchy sequences quotiented out by the equivalence relation that calls Cauchy sequences equivalent if they have the same limit. If you have the full decimal expansion of a number, you can retrieve a representative Cauchy sequence by denoting the $n$th term to be the first $n$ characters in the decimal expansion. Any two decimal expansions which get arbitrarily close together as you pull more terms out (in the Cauchy way) hence represent the exact same number.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Proof. Suppose $x = d_{1}d_{2}d_{3}\ldots$ and $y = d_{1}d_{2}d_{3}\ldots$ are two distinct real numbers with the same decimal representations. Then $0 = d_{1}d_{2}d_{3}\ldots - d_{1}d_{2}d_{3}\ldots = x - y$. But $x$ and $y$ are distinct, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, let's just consider numbers between $0$ and $1$, to avoid the extra complexity of the whole part of numbers.

To answer your question, it's worth trying to understand a bit better what a decimal expansion is. When we say that a number $x \in (0,1)$ has a decimal representation $0.d_1 d_2 d_3...$, what we mean is that $x$ is equal to the infinite series:
$$
x =
\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{d_n}{10^n} 
= \frac{d_1}{10} + \frac{d_2}{100} + \frac{d_3}{1000} + \cdots
$$
Then we must again ask, what does it mean to be equal to an infinite series? Well, the sum of an infinite series is definited by the limit of its partial sums; so in fact we have:
$$
x = \lim \limits_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum \limits_{n=1}^N \frac{d_n}{10^n}
$$
So, if $x$ and $y$ had the same decimal expansion, then they would both be limits of this sequence. Thus the question "can two distinct numbers have the same decimal expansion" in fact amounts to "can a sequence have two distinct limits". The answer is *no*: limits are unique! (This is a basic fact of real analysis.)